# Google Dataflow Sharing Resources Between Windows

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am currently building a google data-flow pipeline that writes to multiple big query tables at run-time. The problem I am currently facing is, I need to re-use the resources like big query service instance, table info etc. (I do not want to re-create those resources every time) but I am not able to cache them in an efficient way.

Currently I am using a simple factory to cache them (using static concurrent hash map). The pipeline does not seem to pick those from the cache (actually it does it for couple of times but most of them are re-created).

I saw some work around with fixed size session windows but I need more simpler solution if there exists any.

So, is there any best practices or solution to the current problem I am facing.
Is there any way to share resources between windows ?

Comment: It's not clear (to me at least) what it is you're asking. Can you share your code please?

Comment: @GrahamPolley we've had to create our own streaming bigquery writer.  This writer has significant startup costs.  We'd like to cache aspects of the writer between windows to reduce overhead.

Comment: @GrahamPolley I am happy to elaborate. Currently i have like tens of millions records I am processing that has an ID field which is my big query table to be created at run-time (around 3,00,000 unique IDs among them).  So whenever I query for those table's information, I want to cache them so that I would have less API calls overhead.

So my question is how can I make those resources to be shared for dataflow pipeline windows, its currently not pulling those information from the cache, its re-creating (I want those resources to be shared among different windows) ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I misplaced the logging information which let to invert the result (my bad). But the solution with Static Factory separate from the pipeline job seem to resolve the resource sharing issue. Hope this helps to anyone having similar issue further :)